# Get running instance of COM object in Python with pywin32

Tags: python, windows, com, win32com

I am attempting to automate actions in Reflection Desktop from python. I have done this successfully with VBA before like this:

```
Set Session = CreateObject("Reflection Workspace")
```

Then this gives me the active session:

```
Set Screen = Session.GetObject("Frame").SelectedView.Control.Screen
```

or this gives me a specific session:

```
Set Screen = Session.tView(iView).Control.Screen
```

When doing this from python I anticipated the COM object should be the same and based on this guide [Attach to a running instance of a COM application](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/attach-to-a-com-instance.html) I should be able to attach to a running application like this:

```
system = win32com.client.GetObject('Reflection Workspace')
```

and while this does not return any errors, I also can not find any usable attributes. If I instead use:

```
system = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('EXTRA.System')
```

I can get the active session using:

```
screen = system.ActiveSession.Screen
```

and everything works. If I run

```
win32com.client.combrowse.main()
```

and look at the running objects, Reflection Workspace is the one that is listed, not EXTRA.System.

I also used

```
win32com.client.makepy.main()
```

to create a python library of Reflection Workspace and in doing so I can list out all the available properties and methods of the object but I do not know how to use that new library to early bind an already active session of the application.

So my questions at this point are:

1. If the COM browser is showing Reflection Workspace and not EXTRA.System why can I connect to EXTRA.System as the running process?
2. Why can I connect to Reflection Workspace but none of the COM attributes that are available when using VBA are available when using python?
3. Can someone point to a guide on how to actually assign a running COM process to an object using the library created by makepy()?

Comment: VBA interfaces with the `IDispatch` interface. Is this true for Python as well?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding a solution to this. It looks like the COM API "EXTRA.System" is kept for  [legacy compatibility](https://docs.attachmate.com/reflection/16-2/vba-prog-guide/legacy-macros.html) and "Reflection Workspace" should be used for new development.

I was sure I had tried already but after posting the question I tried again using GetObject to get the reflection frame object and it worked. So for anyone else trying to do this in python you can the application object using:

```
system = win32com.client.GetObject('Reflection Workspace')
```

then get the active view:

```
screen = system.GetObject("Frame").SelectedView.Control.Screen
```

or get a specific view, where 1 is the view number:

```
screen = system.GetObject("Frame").view(1).Control.Screen
```

After that the methods are the same as the [documentation](https://docs.attachmate.com/reflection/16-2/vba-prog-guide/object-model.html) for GetText, PutText, etc.